# How to start learning disease profiling?

Tags: human-biology

I am student of Biological Sciences and interested to learn profiling in order to characterize the state of organisms (especially diseases). You know that there are different types of profiling like, Genome, Proteome, Metabolic and many more.
I am confused from where should I learn in order to understand principles of profiling.
Kindly, guide me.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you asking about various classifications of diseases?

Comment: Sort of! But characterizing diseases with molecular profiling. Likewise, all skin cancers are not equal but through profiling, we can classify.

Comment: I am focusing more on profiling. It's technique.

Comment: There are many results for the search "disease profiling." You can try this and ask what remains unclear.

Comment: Are there any books related to it?

Comment: Okay! I'll try.